# CustomValidator client function not firing for empty textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have mocked up a very simple page and I am absolutely stumped as to why the javascript wont fire when I tab between the 2 textboxes:-

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test.aspx.cs" inherits="Checkout_test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>c</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkthisvalue(source, args) {
        alert('hello');
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="lbl1" AssociatedControlID="txtUsername" Text="1:" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="username" ID="txtUsername" ValidationGroup="vg"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CustomValidator Enabled="true" ID="cvUsername" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="vg" ControlToValidate="txtUsername" EnableClientScript="true" ClientValidationFunction="checkthisvalue" ValidateEmptyText="true" runat="server">*</asp:CustomValidator>
    <asp:Label ID="lbl2" AssociatedControlID="txtPassword" Text="2:" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="username" ID="txtPassword"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CustomValidator Enabled="true" ID="cvPassword" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtPassword" EnableClientScript="true" ClientValidationFunction="checkthisvalue" ValidateEmptyText="true" runat="server"></asp:CustomValidator>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that both CustomValidators have ValidateEmptyText=true

I've tried this in IE and Chrome with no luck.

Comment: The second validator is missing it's validation group, fyi.

Comment: Thanks - I've added it in but no luck.

Comment: You are missing the * on the password validator, it may be being fired you just can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is not a problem of empty text. The `CustomValidator` won't fire upon tab navigation only if you don't change the control value. (try to put a value in your `TextBox`, navigate with tab, come back to empty the `TextBox`, and navigate again with Tab. The CustomValidator will fire)

When thinking about it, having the validators firing upon a simple tab navigation would be somewhat disturbing for the user.

Anyway, the validators will fire upon form submission (provided you remove the `ValidationGroup` attributes on first `TextBox` and `Validator`), and value changes, which is what they are supposed to do.

Hope this will help,